# They are a way to add automatically each field on a table to corresponding entity?

Tags: spring, spring-roo

I search how to create automaticaly field into entities with reverse engeneering ?

Currently I used:

```
database reverse engineer --schema pkgdbORM  --package org.somewhere.team.project.db
```

But my entities have any field.
I would like to map field from db to be put into each entity.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fields are in .aj files. For example, the fields for EntityA are in EntityA_Roo_DbManaged.aj